# Activex calendar control - customize year dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, activex

I am using calendar Control.
is that possible to set only few years(current year and previous year) in the dropdown?.
Because defaultly it is having list of years (1900 - 2100).

[Sample-screen](http://community.magicsoftware.com/en/library?book=en/uniPaaS/&page=How_Do_I_Implement_ActiveX_Controls_on_a_Page.htm)

Comment: Don't use ActiveX. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: The code i am having is one big application.it is Kind of CR.
it is suggested to use only Activex control.

Comment: Don't do that.  ActiveX controls should not be used.

Comment: Okay,is that possible to set only few years in dropdown?

Comment: @SLaks I have endup using Jquery.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Endup using Jquery.This might help somebody.

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
       changeMonth: true, 
 changeYear: true,
   yearRange: '-2:+0'});
    });  
</script>
```